# Internationalization of the description tag in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I'm doing a maven-site for a project and I want to internationalize it. The good thing is that site generation done by the Maven Site Plugin and the Project Info Reports Plugin is already fully internationalized.
The Maven site plugin use the project.description tag from the pom so as to fill the index page and I was wondering if there is a "nice" way of internationalize this tag.

Thanks !

Comment: As far as i know not. Cause this would require a change within the pom which is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my solution is particularly nice, but at least it works for me ;-) AFAIK you cannot directly internationalize a Maven project's meta data, but you can use Maven's profile facility to simulate that. Proceed like that: create a Maven property, e.g. `i18n.project.description` with the default translation for your project description. Use this property for `project.description`. Then add a profile for every language you want to support (e.g. profiles with id `SWE` and `GER`). In each profile override the description property with the corresponding translation. Then you can use these different profiles to build internationalized sites like so:

`$mvn -P GER site` # builds the German site

`$mvn -P SWE site` # builds the Swedish site

You can mix these profiles with your existing profiles if you have any, e.g.

`$mvn -P GER,development site`

In sum, the relevant parts of your pom.xml could be defined as follows:

```
<project>
    <description>${i18n.project.description}</description>

    <properties>
        <i18n.project.description>Some project description</i18n.project.description>
    </properties>

    ...

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>SWE</id>
            <properties>
                <i18n.project.description>En projektbeskrivning</i18n.project.description>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>GER</id>
            <properties>
                <i18n.project.description>Irgend eine Projektbeschreibung</i18n.project.description>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response which is a good solution when generating the sites with two differents maven commands, but what I'm doing is generating the sites with `<locales>` configuration : `<locales>fr,en</locales>` so the two sites are generated in the same `mvn:site` command and I can't attach one profile for the first locale and one other for the second. Don't you use the internationalization stuff like that ?